# Restrict duplicate records to insert into table at same time

Tags: sql-server

How to restrict duplicate data to insert into table without using primary key and unique constraints?

```
id  dat
----------------------------
1   2019-07-30 14:30:13.830
2   2019-07-30 14:30:13.830
3   2019-07-30 14:31:22.587
4   2019-07-30 14:31:51.633
5   2019-07-30 14:34:35.040
5   2019-07-30 14:34:35.040
```

Here the record with id 5 is inserted at same time

```
declare @id int = 5

if(@id in (select id from ##time))
    print 'already exists'
else
    insert into ##time values (@id, getdate()), (@id, getdate())
```

I tried to restrict duplicate data but the problem is it's not working with duplicate records inserted at same time

Comment: And why no unique constraint/index?

Comment: did you try with Count() function? It will return you count of records in table.

Comment: Your `insert` statement has two rows with same values.

Comment: Using a primary key and/or a unique constraints **ARE** the preferred and simplest ways of doing this - why are you **excluding those** from the get-go?? Doing this "manually" is both annoying, cumbersome, and error-prone......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding a unique constraint to the `dat` column:

```
ALTER TABLE time ADD CONSTRAINT cnstr_dat UNIQUE (dat);
```

This would prevent duplicate records from being inserted.

Comment: Sorry for force update: Is it better to add for Id column? Bcause two diff Id have same datetime (valid case) which in your case it will failed to insert!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
  insert into yourtable (id, dat)
  select distinct id, dat from #temp where id not in (select id from yourtable)
```

This will prevent any duplicate id to be inserted and at the same time select distinct record of non inserted id